# How to use dispatch function in controller Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to use dispatch function in our controller I want to secure my Url when customer purchase a product then they are able to use the URL other wise URL is redirect

My Code is

```
namespace StackExchange\Customer\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $messageManager;

    public function dispatch()
    {
       echo "hiii";
    } 

    public function execute()
    {

    }
```

And the error is

```
Fatal error: Declaration of StackExchange\Customer\Controller\Index\Index::dispatch() must be compatible with Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction::dispatch(Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) in /home/magento2marketplace/app/code/StackExchange/Customer/Controller/Index/Index.php on line 96
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dispatch method must be compatible with the your parent class dispatch method.

```
public function dispatch(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
{
     // your code
     return parent::dispatch($request);
}
```